# can i manage result of ajax with phtml file?

Tags: ajax, zend-framework, view, php

i want manage result of ajax in phtml file, this is my view code that ajax link is there:

```
<div id="container"></div><?php echo $this->ajaxLink("Link Name",
                      $this->baseUrl() ."/admin/index/first/format/json",
                      array('update' => '#container',
                            'method' => 'POST')); ?>
```

this is first action code :

```
public function firstAction()
{
    if($this->_request->isPost()) {         
        // pretend this is a sophisticated database query
        $data = array('red','green','blue','yellow');
        $jsonData = Zend_Json::encode($data);
        $this->view->data = $jsonData;
    }
}
```

this is first.phtml code :

```
<ul><?php foreach ($this->data as $color) : ?><li><?= $color ?></li><?php endforeach; ?></ul>
```

but there is a prob! result of ajax show like this:

> {"data":"[\"red\",\"green\",\"blue\",\"yellow\"]"}

and it don`t use of first.phtml file!

### is there any way fo solve this prob?

Comment: I don't understand why would you do it like this? In first.phtml you want to use PHP's foreach to loop through JSON data? foreach will not be able to iterate through JSON string. You should be iterating through your $data array.

Comment: if i don`t use of json, how about this time? how i can use of phtml file for manage result of ajax?

Comment: phtml must be rendered by php. Ajax will just fetch and display whatever php had generated. You would use JSON only when your firstAction would return JSON string to be processed by a javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

answer : i found the answer with Marcin help ;)

```
public function firstAction()
{
    if($this->_request->isPost()) {         
        // pretend this is a sophisticated database query
        $data = array('red','green','blue','yellow');
        Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance()->disableLayout(); 
        //$jsonData = Zend_Json::encode($data);
        $this->view->data = $data;
    }
}
```

and i delete every json parameter form ajaxlink and init method

```
$ajaxContext = $this->_helper->getHelper('AjaxContext');
    $ajaxContext->addActionContext('first', 'html')
                //->addActionContext('format', 'json')
                ->initContext();
```

every thing is now correct :)